# Can a branch of the argument be defined on a deleted neighborhood of the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, polar-coordinates

I have been reading about invertibility of functions and one subtopic is branches of functions/inverses. While reading about defining branches of the argument, a statement was left as an exercise to prove.

First it says:
"A branch of $\arg(x,y)$ can be defined on an open set $T$ of the $xy$-plane if and only if the polar coordinates of the points in $T$ form an open subset of the $r\theta$-plane that does not intersect the $\theta$-axis or contain any two points of the form $(r,\theta)$ and $(r,\theta+2k\pi)$, where $k$ is a nonzero integer. No subset containing the origin has this property..."

Which I understand, but then it says the following:
"...nor does any deleted neighborhood of the origin"

Which is left as an exercise to prove. I have no inclination to why this would be true so I dont know where to even start. For all points in a deleted neighborhood of $(0,0)$ all points would be mapped to a set with no points $(r,\theta)$ and $(r,\theta+2k\pi)$ and all point have non-zero modulus so I see no contradiction there.

Comment: You have to define $\arg$ as a single-valued, continuous function.  How would you define it on the circle $|z|=1$?  We have $\arg e^{i\theta}=\theta,$ for $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ but when $\theta=2\pi$, continuity demands $\arg z=2\pi$ and single-valuedness demands $\arg z = 0$.

Comment: So you can't define arg(x,y) on any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contain a circle centered at the origin? If thats the case, the fact that it was a deleted neighborhood was not really significant I suppose.

Comment: Actually, I would say just the reverse.  That we can't define it in a deleted neighborhood is significant, because we always want to define analytic functions on connected open sets.  That we can't define $\arg z$ continuously on a circle centered at the origin is just a proof technique.

Comment: Okay, but am I right in thinking that the reason we cant define it in a deleted neighborhood is not because of the deleted neighborhood but rather the fact that it is a circle centered at the origin?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I think.